# What's the Point of Upgrading My Horse?

Tags: pixelry

In [Pixelry](http://www.indievania.com/games/pixelry), one of the things you can upgrade at the forge is your horse's movement speed.  Is there any particular reason I should do this?  The game doesn't specifically mention that upgrading your speed will increase your damage, etc, but then again the game isn't entirely clearly translated.

Does upgrading my horse give me any *actual* benefits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now the horse only gives you speed for a gameplay improvement, but in next versions now that the fight system is corrected, it will increase your damage and we are planning to give the horse a complete set of different upgrades!